# Run a php or py script once at a unique dynamic wanted time

Tags: scripts, php, cron, 19.04

I have a small bot currently written in `php` but i can switch to `py` if need be.

It basically gathers data from an api about tasks that need to be ran only once in order to be updated the next day at certain unique times

Each day at `UTC+0 00:00` i use a `cron job` to gather that data from the api.

For example a task might need to run at `UTC+0 09:00` another one at `UTC+0 10:15` and another one at `UTC+0 11:30`. The next day there are new tasks that need to run at different times.

Now since those tasks are only available for that day i don't think that setting a cron job for each of them at the desired time is a solution and then delete the cron job.

Therefore, how do i run a script just when the task needs to be updated?

For now i'm running a cron job each minute and if there is a task within a minute range i'm running another script that updates that task but that seems messy to me and i'm wondering if i could do something about it.

P.S: I'm using a droplet from digitalocean that runs on `Ubuntu 19.04 - disco`

Comment: Take a look at the `at` command. With `at` you can schedule a job to run once at a specific time in the future.

Comment: Oh, was it that easy? X_X Can i run this command using php/py?

Comment: Both languages should have some kind of `system ()` call .. for php i googled `php execute shell command` and got this as first hit: https://www.binarytides.com/execute-shell-commands-php/

Comment: You should add your comment/s as an answer :P so i can mark it as preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To schedule a command to run one time in the future, you can use `at` command. See the manual page (`man at`) for how to specify time and date.

From php you can use the `system ()` range of commands to call any system command, inclusive `at`. Python also have a system but also a subprocess.run command.

- [PHP](https://www.binarytides.com/execute-shell-commands-php/)
- [PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)
- [man at](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at)

Comment: Saved me a ton of headaches. Thanks! :D

Comment: i really have some problems in using php to run this command cause i can't run it in one line O_O can you help me? Or should i open a question about this? :-?

Comment: @emma .. I thing you should open a new question with an example of your code .. you already did, I see ;-)